# Por que no Python podemos definir um índice de um Dict como um Tuple?

Tags: python, dicionário, tupla

Eu observei que no Python, podemos adicionar valores do tipo `tuple` como índice de um `dict` (dicionário).

Exemplo:

```
test = {}

test[(1, 2, 3)] = ("um", "dois", "tres")

print test // {(1, 2, 3): ('um', 'dois', 'tres')}
```

E depois da definição, como acessamos o valor para a chave que definimos como `tuple`?

E qual é a finalidade disso?

Comment: Tenho essa dúvida porque venho do PHP, e, "lá", não se pode definir um índice de um array como um outro tipo que não seja int ou string (nem float aceita).

Comment: Cuidado que Dicionários em Python são bem diferentes dos "arrays" no PHP - "arrays" em PHP são um tipo de objeto coringa, que funciona tanto como uma sequência, com ínidces numéricos quanto como um mapeamento com chaves de strings. São conceitos separados, que em Pyrhon ficam bem separados - os tipos mais comuns são listas e tuplas para sequências, e dicionários para mapeamentos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dicionários de Python não tem por que ter restrições sobre como estruturas de dados são implementadas em outras linguagens.

As restrições para que um objeto possa ser usado como chave de um dicionário são: o objeto deve implementar um método `__hash__` que retorna um valor único e constante; o objeto tem comparação de igualdade com outros objetos (`__eq__`) - e que nem esse hash nem a condição de igualdade varie enquanto o objeto for uma chave de dicionário. Em geral, para simplificar dizemos que objetos imutáveis podem ser chaves de dicionário - mas seguindo essas restrições até objetos mutáveis podem servir.

O "qual a utilidade" varia enormemente: depende do que você quer fazer - tuplas em geral são práticas por que deixam você usar um dicionário como uma matriz esparça, de cara - bastando usar o método "get" para pegar valores:

```
W = H = 10
a = {}
a[5,5] = 1
print ("\n".join(", ".join(str(a.get((x,y), 0))  for x in range(W))  for y in range(H)) )
```

Nesse exemplo, uso o índice no método `get` por que ele permite especificar um valor padrão para quando a chave não existe - (o que acontece para todos as combinações de x e y, menos a (5,5) que eu declarei). A saída é:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Tuplas são excepcionalmente práticas por que os parênteses em volta podem ser omitidos quando usados em um contexto sem ambiguidades - como índices dentro de colchetes (veja o exemplo acima).

Mas objetos que representem data e hora, com comparações ricas, conjuntos congelados (frozen sets), até funções podem ser usadas como chaves para dicionário (em aplicações de log, por exemplo, que contabilizem o número de vezes em que uma função é chamada, ou que façam cache) - é legal não ter uma restrição artificial.

Um contexto em que se deve tomar cuidado com chaves diferentes é em aplicações que tem que serializar os dados como JSON, como por exemplo, APIs rest, ou em chamadas a alguns bancos de dados não relacionais: o padrão JSON exige que as chavves de dcionário sejam strings.

Comment: +1, mas não é verdade que as chaves precisam ter o método `__hash__` — isso só é verdade se a chave tiver o método `__eq__` também; se ela não tiver nenhum dos dois, você pode usar o dicionário, mas a comparação é feita pelo `id` do objeto: `{object(): object() for i in range(10)}` é um `dict` com 10 entradas.

Comment: Verdade - mas a implementação do dicionário continua usando o hash do objeto - é que se ele não tiver uma função de `__hash__`, o valor é baseado no ID.

Answer (score 3):

Para acessar, apenas usamos a `tuple` como chave, seguindo o seu exemplo:

```
print test[(1,2,3)] #Isso retornará ('um', 'dois', 'tres')
```

Com relação a utilidade disso, dependerá da sua implementação. Por exemplo, imagine um banco de dados que um certo conjunto de valores de uma linha me retornem um valor, eu poderia utilizar a `tuple` com essa finalidade para acessar um valor específico.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as outras respostas, a [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html) (uma biblioteca pra fazer operações matriciais) abusa esse fato pra permitir que você faça operações em blocos:

- se `M` é um `numpy.array`, `M[5:10, 10:15]` é uma matriz 5 × 5 que consiste dos elementos na interseção das 5ª à 9ª linhas de `M` com as 10ª à 14ª coluna de `M`;
- se `L` é um vetor unidimensional, `L[numpy.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21])]` é um vetor que consiste só dos elementos nas posições da sequência de Fibonacci;
- se `N` é uma matriz qualquer, `N[N < 0] = -N` atribui a `N` o valor absoluto de cada uma de suas entradas.

A [documentação do `numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) tem mais abusos criativos da indexação do Python.

(Sim, é verdade que o `numpy.array` não é um dicionário, mas sim um objeto que sobrecarrega seu método `__getitem__` pra permitir `M[…]`, mas acho que isso é um bom exemplo de porque é útil permitir objetos arbitrários entre os colchetes.)